# Bootstrap Image Overflowing Page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

On my [page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6RAX.png), I've inserted an image that is overflowing. I'm using Bootstrap, and `image-responsive` doesn't seem to be making the image the right height. Furthermore, I don't want to explicitly change the height of the image or change the size the text to fit the image. If it helps, the image is placed inside a modal.

HTML:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="header">
            <h1 class="header-primary">
                <em>The Chrysalids</em> by John Wyndham
            </h1>
            <h1 class="header-primary-subheader">
                Novel Study
            </h1>
        </div>

        <img class="img-responsive mx-auto img" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/69/b3/d3/69b3d30e9a7c7245ba8f8262973597f7.jpg" alt="Cover">

        <div class="close-Btn text-center">
            <button id="close-Btn" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Begin</button>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.img {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.modal {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 200;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden; 
    background-color: #FFF;
    vertical-align: center;
}

.modal-content {
    padding: 20px; 
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
```